# How might I create the effect in this logo design?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, logo

[image: This is a past logo design made by a YouTuber I watch]

I would be interested to learn how to do the effect shown in the image, particularly the way the logo maintains the silhouette despite being composed of lines

Comment: What have you tried? What problems did you run into? What resources have you looked at?

Comment: Photoshop > Filter > Stylize > Wind > Blast.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like Scott pointed out in the comments, you can use the Blast Filter to achieve this look. Additionally, you would want to have an original layer of the cutout or "silhouette" as you say to use as a mask. Analyzing further, the tone and colors inside look to be created with Filter > Render > Clouds using contrasting colors.

### Putting it in action

So, I went ahead and put it together in Photoshop and here's the workflow I came up with. First, the finished example:

[image: blasted]

Here's what my layers look like:

[image: layers]

### Explanation

What I did first was to create the folder that will hold everything. From there, open your vector (preferrably) or whatever contains your shape. Ideally, you want this to be in vector so that you can scale.

1. Ctrl/cmd-click your shape/object layer so that it creates a
   selection, select the **folder** that contains everything, and go to
   `Layer > Layer Mask > Reveal Selection`.
2. Make a new layer above your graphic, and fill it with whatever color
   you want. Set your foreground and background colors to the two
   contrasting colors you want to have in your image.
3. Now, with your newly filled layer selected, go to `Filter > Render >
   Clouds`. Do this a few times if you don't like the first initial
   result by hitting ctrl/cmd-F.
4. Next, go to `Filter > Stylize > Wind...` and choose the *Stagger*
   option. This may distort your layer, so after running the filter you
   might need to reposition your layer to fill your
   graphic/object/shape.
5. Now, right-click on the same layer and choose *Create Clipping
   Mask*. This will mask the colors to the graphic on the layer below,
   which is important for the next step.
6. Select your graphic/object/shape layer and go to `Filter > Stylize >
   Wind...` and choose the *Blast* option this time. You should see a
   dialog if your layer isn't already a smart object asking you to
   choose to convert or rasterize. Convert it to a smart object.

---

*At this point, you should have a pretty close example of the effect. It's not exact, but I didn't spend more than 5-10 minutes on it. I'm sure if you put a little more time into it, you can achieve a better result.*